# Importing class from other directory - Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, import, package, python-import

I'm running into a problem of importing class.
The program structure is:

```
gui_learn/
|--__init__.py
|--run.py
|--oo_part/
   |--__init__.py
   |--wheat_class
|--gui_part/
   |--__init__.py
   |--crop_window.py
```

My wheat_class.py:

```
class Wheat:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

My crop_window.py contains:

```
def display_product():
    print(wheat_class.Wheat())
```

And run.py:

```
from oo_part import wheat_class
from gui_part.crop_window import display_product
display_product()
```

The error: NameError: name 'wheat_class' is not defined

Comment: Your `crop_window` module needs to import `wheat_class`. Importing them both in `run` doesn't do it. Each module has it's own namespace. Try moving the `from oo_part import wheat_class` from `run.py` to `crop_window.py`. I'd also suggest that you remove the `__init__.py` file from the top level folder, since you're not using it as a package (otherwise you'd need to run `run.py` with `python -m gui_learn.run` and all the imports would need to be fixed).

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks for the explanation, I should have studied namespace when I came across it.